# Embedding Rails in Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

My goal is to embed a full Ruby on Rails app in a Wordpress site. Ideally, the staff should be able to edit the non-Rails parts of the site just like any Wordpress site, including content, theme, menus, etc. When the user clicks a link to a certain page, it should show the Rails content within the Wordpress template—headers, menus, sidebars, etc.—all of which should look the same as the rest of the site. I'd much prefer to do the presentation of the Rails content within Rails, where I can use Slim, CoffeeScript, SASS, and all of the other built in presentational magic, rather than setting Rails up as just a JSON server and having to muck around with PHP to retrieve and format the data.

I've tried a few techniques so far, but each has its downsides:

1. First, I tried embedding the Rails app in an iframe, but iframes are clunky, and I couldn't get it to expand or contract to the height of the content.
2. Second, I tried creating a special Wordpress template file that loads the Rails content using PHP's `file_get_contents` function. That worked okay, but required a lot of jankiness to get URLs to transfer over, including having to add a question mark into the URL for a certain subpage to get Wordpress to ignore it and pass it through. It's also a little slow because it's loading content from two different dynamic systems. And I never could figure out how to get cookies to pass through to Rails, which is essential for this app.
3. My third solution was to create a blank page on Wordpress (not linked to anywhere) and write a method in Rails that pulls that page, creates a layout file, and then uses that as the layout for the content. So the whole page is actually being served by Rails, but to the user it looks just like Wordpress, and because Wordpress doesn't use relative URLs in links, they all work just fine. The trouble there is that changes to the Wordpress template (including menus, template files, theme options) don't take effect on the Rails pages until that method is run. I set up a cron job to run it every 15 minutes, but that's not ideal, and something tells me there must be a better way.

This seems like something that would be pretty common, but I haven't been able to find any solutions online. Has anyone else made this work?

Comment: Option 3 sounds the most feasible. You could create a template or function in WordPress that writes out a layout file with ERB tags and everything and places it in a shared location. Then when a visitor comes to the Rails application page, they are just hitting Rails and not WordPress, and the application uses the WP generated layout file.  EDIT: To help with the caching/update issue, you could use some WordPress action hooks to tell WordPress to re-generate the layout file when specific actions take place (i.e. post published, menu changed, etc)

Comment: @bcole I looked into Wordpress action hooks, and it looks doable, but there could be a lot of different actions that might change the template and I'd have to find them all. I think I'd also have to monitor the file system for changes to theme files and hook into that too... and probably also still use a cron job as a backup in case I didn't catch all the ways the template might change.